# Use Input Parameter of procedure to declare %Rowtype record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert the data into a table using Bulk Collect.
Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure insert_via_bulk_collect authid current_user
as 
    lc_status number;
    cursor lc_old_tb_data is select * from old_table_name;

    type lc_old_tb_type is table of old_table_name%rowtype;
    lc_old_tb_row lc_old_tb_type;
begin

    open lc_old_tb_data;
    loop 
        fetch lc_old_tb_data bulk collect into lc_old_tb_row;

        forall i in 1..lc_old_tb_row.count
            insert into new_table_name values lc_old_tb_row(i);

        commit;

        exit when lc_old_tb_data%notfound;
    end loop;
    close lc_old_tb_data;  

end insert_via_bulk_collect;
```

It's working for me. But I want to pass the table name dynamically.
like

```
insert_via_bulk_collect(new_tb_nm varchar2(30), old_tb_name varchar2(30))
```

But I am not able to use those variables in cursor and declaring the record of `OLD_TABLE%rowtype`.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you:  insert into new_table_name select *   from old_table_name. Saves you a lot of code and it's a lot faster.

Comment: @Rene, I have tried this. But its taking time so I am trying to optimise it. My table size is like 150 GB and using "insert into new_table_name select * from old_table_name" will exhaust temp tablespace due to which I am inserting the record in chunks of 500000 rows at a time.

Comment: I wasn't aware that insert select from takes any temp space if there isn't a join or sort operation. Have you tried it? What errors did you run into?

Comment: I got this error - ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace

Comment: Maybe you have simplified the code before posting, because I don't see any 500K chunk definition. The code above will fetch all 150GB into memory at once (so the loop is redundant). Also I can't see where you use any temp space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_VIA_BULK_COLLECT 
(NEW_TABLE_NAME  varchar2, OLD_TABLE_NAME  varchar2)
    as 
         l_str varchar2(4000);
    begin
         l_str := 'declare
         CURSOR lc_old_tb_data IS SELECT * FROM ' || OLD_TABLE_NAME || ';
         TYPE lc_old_tb_type IS TABLE OF '|| OLD_TABLE_NAME || '%rowtype;
         lc_old_tb_row lc_old_tb_type;     
         begin
              Open lc_old_tb_data;
              loop 
                   fetch lc_old_tb_data bulk collect into lc_old_tb_row;

                   FORALL i IN 1..lc_old_tb_row.count
                   INSERT INTO ' || NEW_TABLE_NAME || ' VALUES lc_old_tb_row(i);

                   COMMIT;

                   exit when lc_old_tb_data%notfound;
              end loop;
              close lc_old_tb_data; 
              end; ';

         dbms_output.put_line (l_str);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str; 

    end insert_via_bulk_collect;
```

You can add Exception handing. Also it is recommended to add limit for fetching of data as below `fetch lc_old_tb_data bulk collect into lc_old_tb_row l_size;` you can put l_size value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it is better to use direct `insert ... select ...`. In your case, you can combine this way with `execute immediate`:

```
create or replace procedure insert_via_bulk_collect(new_tb_nm varchar2, old_tb_name varchar2) is
begin
  execute immediate 'insert into ' || new_tb_nm || 
      '(<columns list>) select <columns list> from ' || old_tb_nm; 
end;
```